# How vscode debug test golang test case

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I unit test the code I've written, it turns out that the result is wrong. At this point, I `break points` in `the unit test` and `the code under test`, and then run the debug test, hoping to step through the debugging to find the error, but it directly returns the same result as the run test.
I don't know where I am going wrong, my config file is as follows

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
```

The debug results are as follows

```
Starting: /data/gopath/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:33340 --log-dest=3 from /data/gopath/src/gopractise-demo/sorts
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:33340
Type 'dlv help' for list of commands.
--- FAIL: TestHeapSort (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestHeapSort/heapSort_sort1 (0.00s)
        heap_test.go:38: HeapSort() = [5 1 10 3 6 12 2 4 7 11 9 8], want [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
    --- FAIL: TestHeapSort/heapSort_sort2 (0.00s)
        heap_test.go:38: HeapSort() = [3 5 8 6 1 4 2 7], want [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
FAIL
Process 28790 has exited with status 1
Detaching
dlv dap (28753) exited with code: 0
```

It's not the single-step debugging I expected.

I did not find this error related to the `debug test`, looking forward to your answer, thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: How about enabling the trace and checking whether the breakpoints are all set correctly? https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#troubleshooting